# Is there a drop-down (md-select) component in Angular 2 Material?

Tags: angular

Is `md-select` supported in Angular 2 Material yet?

Looking at the Git Repository, I don't see any component to support the drop-down feature.

https://github.com/angular/material2/tree/master/src/components

When I add @angular2-material/select in package.json, it complains about package not found in the repository.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is an md-select

```
<form>  <md-select placeholder="Favorite food" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" name="food">    <md-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
  {{food.viewValue}}    </md-option>  </md-select>
 <p> Selected value: {{selectedValue}} </p></form>
```

and for the TS you could have the following

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
selector: 'select-form-example',
templateUrl: './select-form-example.html',
})
  export class SelectFormExample {
  selectedValue: string;

  foods = [
    {value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak'},
    {value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza'},
    {value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos'}
  ];
}
```

Check out this [link](https://material.angular.io/components/component/select) and [this](https://github.com/angular/material2/tree/master/src/lib/select)

Answer (score 1):

I am not saying it doesn't exist, however from my research it looks like you have to html it :/ here is a good link on a drop down done in angular 2. http://www.angulartypescript.com/angular-2-dropdown/

You also can mash together a drop down with ng-for but it does not look nearly as clean or practical. I believe egghead.io does a tutorial on it.